# Query and sum in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello I need help in creating a formula with query and sum in google sheet

Here are the condition:
count of all(Column A= a certain number or a specific cell) and Column E=either of the states-up to 4 state

Hope someone can assist me on this.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: here's the Google drive link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zkkvZMNaWl0JLygz9PbFx5Edvcgvy5KD/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112477829724230710670&rtpof=true&sd=true @player0

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:E, "select E,sum(A) where A is not null group by E label sum(A)''")
```

[image]

Comment: i think its different to the one i needed.  IF Column A =1, then it would lookup and get the sum of all states(AZ,OH,MN,FL)

Comment: i think what i need is by using query, 2 conditions would be met and count how many fulfills the conditions: Column A= 1 then Column E(would only count  corresponding AZ,OH,MN,FL)